# Skimage.io.read imread a PIL Object

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

So I was working with skimage for some image preprocessing (i'm very new to it). I have a `PIL` Image object and wanted to convert to a skimage image with `skimage.io.imread()`. I know that I can just save the image and then run `imread` on that file, but I was wondering if there was a way I could read the `PIL` Image object from the code itself. I tried to run `imread` on the PIL Image object itself but I end up getting errors.

`OSError: Cannot understand given URI: <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=192....`

Anyone know how I can solve this in skimage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scikit-Image** stores images as Numpy arrays, so you just need to make a Numpy array from your **PIL Image**:

```
ImageForScikit = np.array(YourPILImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may review [imageio documentation](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) related to the function [imread](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html?highlight=imread#imageio.imread) for including in your code the attribute format and code as follows just in case the image format is PNG: `imageio.imread(filename, format = 'PNG')`